# How to extract request headers in express.static

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js

I am using express.static middleware as I do not want to list down each and every asset individually in the routes. All my routes are handled via index.html as I am using Vue JS.

Because of a feature requirement, I need to extract some information from the request headers but I don't see request in either options or documentation for express.static.

Here is my code

```
const staticFileMiddleware = express.static(__dirname);
app.use(staticFileMiddleware);
app.use(history({
  disableDotRule: true,
  verbose: true
}));

// here I wanted to print out req.headers but its not available anywhere
// console.log(req.headers); <------------------------------

const port = 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a middleware:

```js
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.headers)
  next()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In node, the headers are only available on request so you need to create a middleware who has access to the request.

```
app.use((req,res,next) => {
console.log(req.headers)
next()
})
```